# How to use scrollWidth value of parent element using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set width and height for `cover` element same as `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` of `container` element. So during the scrolling it will fully cover container. At the moment it uses `width` and `height` of container element cropped by scroll.

The whole area should be covered by green color. Is it possible to do using only css?

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 4px blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Javascript code to do it.

Quick reminder: `document.querySelector(".cover")` here return just the first element met but if there are more use `document.querySelectorAll()`

EDIT : You can do it with only CSS too by wrapping the rows in the cover (It's why i put Javascript in comments)

```js
/*const { scrollWidth, scrollHeight } = document.querySelector(".container");

const coverElement = document.querySelector(".cover");

coverElement.style.width = `${scrollWidth}px`;
coverElement.style.height = `${scrollHeight}px`; */
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 4px blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sileax Do you know how to do the same using only css?

Comment: @greenfield Yes i just edit my post. Wrapping rows with the cover and removing the (width, height CSS property of the cover that no longer needed)

Comment: I don't want to change structure of elements. I want to add cover for container without wrapping its content

Comment: So i've no answer for you on the CSS side apart this one. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your the final goal is, but have you tried simply applying the background to the container?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,128,0,.5);
}

.row {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 4px blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll clarify. The final goal is to set ```width``` for child element the same value as ```scrollWidth```  of parent element

Comment: Oh no you explained that just fine! My point was, that depending on what was going to happen further to this UI element, you might not need the extra background div. But from other comments I read that the given structure was important, so I guess this is not the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` of the parent.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const cover = document.querySelector('.cover');
cover.style.height = container.scrollHeight + "px";
cover.style.width = container.scrollWidth + "px";
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 4px blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it using only css?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid 2px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.cover {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.row {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    border: solid 4px blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container cover">
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```